# PIL: ImageGrab.grab() failed - OSError: screen grab failed after some time

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

I use `ImageGrab.grab()` to take a screenshot of the screen.
I have a function that infinitely takes screenshots with a certain delay. However, after about 2 hours or so, an error `OSError: screen grab failed` occurs when calling this function.

I found a similar problem here: https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/1601,
however, I am not taking screenshots on a remote server, but on my own PC.

What causes this to happen and what can be done?

OS: *Windows 10*

Example code:

```
from PIL import ImageGrab
from threading import Thread
import time


DELAY = 1.0


def shot(bbox):
    im = ImageGrab.grab(bbox)
    return im.load()


def screen_scan():
    while True:
        shot(None)
        time.sleep(DELAY)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Thread(target=screen_scan, daemon=True).start()
    while True:
        input()
```

Comment: AFAIK: GH issue you linked  doesnt really matter if its remote or local machine - point being is that if screensaver becomes active, any UI interaction is blocked by windows security measures..

Comment: @rasjani, I use the screen scan for macros for the game.
I move the mouse at the right moments and movements happen about every 15-20 seconds.
Screensaver does not appear, just at some point the screen capture stops working.